# Empty flowfile after trying to write content as Excel

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I have following code to read .csv and transform it to Excel:

```
@Grab("org.apache.poi:poi:5.0.0")
@Grab("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.0.0")
@Grab("com.opencsv:opencsv:4.6")

import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.SpreadsheetVersion;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.AreaReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile)
   return

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, { inputStream, outputStream ->
try {
        SXSSFWorkbook sxssfWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook();
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        
        sxssfWorkbook.setCompressTempFiles(true);
        SXSSFSheet sxssfSheet = sxssfWorkbook.createSheet("Sheet");
        sxssfSheet.setRandomAccessWindowSize(100);

        String[] strHeaders = null;
            String[] dataRow = null;
            int rowNum = 0;
            while ((dataRow = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
                if (rowNum == 0) strHeaders = dataRow;
                Row currentRow = sxssfSheet.createRow(rowNum);
                for (int i = 0; i < dataRow.length; i++) {
                    String cellValue = dataRow[i];
                    currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(cellValue);
                }
                rowNum++;
            }
        int lastRow = rowNum -1;
        int lastCol = strHeaders.length -1;
        AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference(new CellReference(0, 0), new CellReference(lastRow, lastCol), SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);

        XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = sxssfSheet.getWorkbook().getXSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet xssfSheet = xssfWorkbook.getSheet(sxssfSheet.getSheetName());
        XSSFTable xssfTable = xssfSheet.createTable(areaReference);
        
        //xssfTable.updateHeaders(); // this cannot work since xssfSheet does not contain any data until now
        for (int i = 0; i < strHeaders.length; i++) {
            String columnHeader = strHeaders[i];
            if (xssfTable.getCTTable().getTableColumns().getTableColumnList().size() > i) 
                xssfTable.getCTTable().getTableColumns().getTableColumnList().get(i).setName(columnHeader);
        }
        xssfTable.getCTTable().addNewTableStyleInfo();
        XSSFTableStyleInfo style = (XSSFTableStyleInfo)xssfTable.getStyle();
        style.setName("TableStyleLight9");
        style.setShowColumnStripes(false);
        style.setShowRowStripes(true);
        xssfTable.getCTTable().addNewAutoFilter().setRef(areaReference.formatAsString());

        sxssfWorkbook.write(outputStream)
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
} as StreamCallback)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

But it returns empty flowfile after `ExecuteGroovyScript`.

[image]

Before I tested this in `IntelliJ IDEA` with Java. But reading from file and saving to file:

```
FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("P:\\test.xlsx");
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("P:\\test.csv"));
```

So, I guess something wrong with inputstream/outputstream?

P.S. To test some values from cell I decided to write some value to attributes:

```
...
sxssfWorkbook.write(outputStream);
flowFile.putAttribute('test', sxssfSheet.getRow(5).getCell(1).toString())
...
```

But flowfile doesn't contain this attribute.
What did I wrong?

Comment: 1st - remove try-catch - because you are just hiding error.

Comment: Removed try-catch, error is `ExecuteGroovyScript[id=0841316a-9e1f-1d4b-b6b5-5e1d9f76dc52] groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.apache.poi.ss.util.AreaReference(org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference, org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference, org.apache.poi.ss.SpreadsheetVersion): groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.apache.poi.ss.util.AreaReference(org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference, org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference, org.apache.poi.ss.SpreadsheetVersion)`

Comment: But `AreaReference` has this constructor: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/AreaReference.html